# Need to update the Spring-boot-admin UI url

Tags: spring-boot-admin

How do I update the default URL for the Spring-Boot admin UI.
By default it comes up at `http://localhost:8080` . I want the admin UI to come up at something like `http://localhost:8080/mypath`

Comment: Was finally able to do it by adding the following property in application.properties `spring.boot.admin.context-path=/mypath `